# Make Image a header full screen (width) css

Tags: css, header

I am trying to extend my header to image cover the full page. https://trongcotruyen.vn I have been trying everything for hours now. any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chrome-debugging tool (press F12 (Mac: Cmd+Opt+I )) to easily see what's wrong with your CSS. In your particular case, one of the parent elements is having horizontal padding, margin and max-width set. Removing them will do the job, just add the following CSS in your CSS file:

```
.banner-ads > .uk-container {
    max-width: initial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @putadesign if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.